# Check In: Operation not performed Could not find file *.csproj.vspscc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am having issues with check in my code files because of some changes I have made to the project and solution. I have renamed project files, added different project files in the solution and added many files in the existing project.
Now I am getting an error while checking in the code.
The error details are:

> Check In: Operation not performed Could not find file
>   '....Console.csproj.vspscc'.

How do I create a vspscc file if it does not get created on its own?

Any help would be great and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This looks pretty stupid on my part. I restarted my Visual Studio and I could perform the check in because Visual Studio created the vspscc file when it opened the projects and solution.

Answering my own question as fast as possible so nobody else prints my own negligence before me.

And for anybody who needs an answer as how to create a vspscc file, restart the visual studio IDE

Answer (score 10):

I have also seen this in another situation (VS2012) where a simple restart didn't do the trick.

I had a number of new projects which I had added to an existing solution but in the wrong place. Undoing and re-adding seemed to be fine until check-in, where it complained that the newly added projects and related .vspscc files could not be found. It was looking for them in the original location rather than where they are now.

Resolution was to go to the Source Control Explorer, which still had check-in items against these files in their original (but non-existing) locations, as well as the files in their correct locations. Selecting these errant references and "Undo pending Changes" for these files did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I'd try using File/SourceControl/ChangeSourceControl dialog and unbind (if necessary) then rebind the project to TFS to recreate the .csproj.vspscc.

Answer (score 1):

I removed projects and have same issue, so my solution was to re-create the same projects with same name, then remove them cleanly :-) I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I Visual Studio/TFS couldn't fine the .csproj file. Anyway, with the help of a colleague I was able to determine that the issue was within TFS itself. TFS may have a different view of your source code than Visual Studio does. I had created the wrong type of project (I'll call it Proj1) and deleted it from within VS. Then created the correct project type, which I'll call Proj2. When I when to check it into TFS it complained about Prog1.csproj, which confused me because I couldn't see it within VS. What I learned was that you have to go into TFS's Source Control Explorer. From there you'll see how TFS sees things. Sure enough, there was Proj1.csproj (and some other related files to Proj1). What I had to do within Source Control Explorer was undo the pending check-in's of those files and folders which I didn't want to check in and no longer existed anyway. Then TFS was happy and I could perform the check-in.